# Convert iso_week to calendar date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, iso

I've been searching though the archives without finding what I am looking for- I'd be happy for some guidance.

I have a data set where I want to report aggregated number of appointments by provider (STAFFID) and work week, the latter defined by the week's Monday date. I've played with `datepart(iso_week, appointment_date) as week_of_yr` which gets me part of the way there- I can group by week to get the right numbers. However, I can't figure out if there's a simple way to display the date of the week's Monday given the iso_week integer (and year).

I found [ISO8601 Convert Week Date to Calendar Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369372/iso8601-convert-week-date-to-calendar-date) helpful, though I do not know whether (or how) I can automate that process for many values at once.

Here's the tidbit of code I have. Ideally I could add another expression to the select statement which would display the desired date.

```
     select STAFFID
     , count(*) as appointment_ct
     , datepart(iso_week, appointment_date) as iso_wk --this returns the week # of the year as an int
     from [dbo].[view_APPT_DATA]
     where program_code in ('99999') 
     and appointment_date >= '1/1/2016' and appointment_date <='3/31/2016' 
     group by iso_wk, STAFFID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would find the [first Monday of that year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525710/first-monday-of-the-year-in-sql-server) and then use DATEADD to add the number of weeks to that day

```
 select STAFFID
 , count(*) as appointment_ct
 , datepart(iso_week, appointment_date) as iso_wk --this returns the week # of the year as an int
 , dateadd(week, datepart(week, DATEADD(DAY, (@@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dateadd(year, datepart(year, appointment_date) - 1900, 0)) + (8 - @@DATEFIRST) * 2) % 7, dateadd(year, datepart(year, appointment_date) - 1900, 0)))  as monday_wk 
 from [dbo].[view_APPT_DATA]
 where program_code in ('99999') 
 and appointment_date >= '1/1/2016' and appointment_date <='3/31/2016' 
 group by iso_wk, STAFFID, monday_wk
```

Comment: Thanks @cha. The idea works, though your SQL gives errors regarding the correct number of arguments for the dateadd fxn. I ended up adding the expression "dateadd(wk, (iso_wk-1), '1/4/2016')" to my select statement, which works without declaring variables but of course depends on the year being 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get the cha's query to return correct results for "special" years that have overlapping weeks.
This is the (inline) function i ended up with to calculate iso week to first day of that week:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FN_ISOWEEK_TO_DAY (
    -- ISOWeek in format YYYYWW
    @pISOWeek INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
        SELECT  DATEADD(week, CAST(RIGHT(@pISOWeek, 2) AS INT) - 1  
                - CASE WHEN (@@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(YEAR, cast(LEFT(@pISOWeek, 4) AS INT) - 1900, 0)) + (8 - @@DATEFIRST) * 2) % 7 >= 4 -- means first monday is one week ahead
                        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ,   DATEADD(DAY, (@@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(YEAR, cast(LEFT(@pISOWeek, 4) AS INT) - 1900, 0)) + (8 - @@DATEFIRST) * 2) % 7,  DATEADD(YEAR, cast(LEFT(@pISOWeek, 4) AS INT) - 1900, 0)))
        AS firstDay
```

Some test code:

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM (
            SELECT  202001, 20191230
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  202053, 20201228
        ) x (dt, expectedValue)
    CROSS APPLY dbo.FN_ISOWEEK_TO_DAY(x.dt) y
```